# Is it possible to force a neo4j transaction to timeout?

Tags: performance, transactions, neo4j

This might be typical Java 7 boilerplate for accessing some Neo4j data.

Is there any mechanism in existence whereby you can set up the transaction to automatically fail and rollback based upon a timeout?

```
try (Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx()) {
    Node node = // Get some Nodes ...
    Iterable<Relationship> rels = node.getRelationships(...);
    for (Relationship rel : rels) {
        // Oh no! This is a super-node with a billion Relationships!
    }
    tx.success();
    return data;
}
```

I guess just have `int count = 0` and increment each iteration, and then:

```
if(count > XYZ) throw TakingTooLongException(count)
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You can also just check with `node.getDegree()` upfront before your loop, which is a constant time operation for dense nodes and a small counter for all others (<50 rels).

Otherwise there is also an execution guard, but I'm not sure for how long it will survive.

You can just return from the tx without calling `tx.success()` and it should be rolled back.

Comment: I'm going to try this. The code was recently upgraded from `1.9.8`, so new features are, well, new ...