# Neo4j timeout not working

Tags: neo4j

I am running some tests on Neo4j, including the execution of a query computing the longest shortest path of my big graph. As I expect that query to take really long time I used the instructions I found [here](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/17/neo4j-setting-query-timeout/) to set a timeout of 30 minutes.

I noticed that the query kept on running for long time (I had to manually kill it) even if the timeout was set. 
However, this issue disappeared if I set a really low timeout (e.g. 10 millis). 
Does anybody know what's going on?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know - `guard` functionality is deprecated (check answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745865/is-it-possible-to-force-a-neo4j-transaction-to-timeout)). There is no mention about this functionality in current stable Neo4j release documentation.

I think best you can do in this case - manage query execution time at client side. This can give you enough flexibility for managing different timeout times, for different queries.

In Java, for example you can start you query in separate `Thread`, and wait for result until some timeout is reached.

#### Neo4j 2.3+

If you are not using latest stable Neo4j release (2.3.1 ast time of writing), then you definitely should try to upgrade.

2.3 was quite significant release, with a lot of bugfixes and new functionality. So, probably your issue is already fixed.

#### Plugin

Additionally you can create simple [Neo4j plugin](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html), which will:

- Receive query and timeout value
- Execute in Neo4j via `GraphDatabaseService`
- If execution reaches timeout, then terminate transaction
- If query executes successfully, return response

Comment: Thanks for you answer @FylmTM, would that stop the execution of the query in the server? I'm asking because I tried to set a timeout in a REST API call but, while my client stopped and got an exception, the server was still high in CPU and I guess it was still processing the query since it was the only request it got.

Comment: @Alberto are you using latest Neo4j version?

Comment: I'm using 2.2.6 and, unfortunately, since I started reporting results with that version, I'm bound to that

Comment: If i remember correctly, in Neo4j 2.3 this issue is fixed. If you close request before it finish, it will close and rollback transaction. I have updated answer with info about Neo4j plugin.

Comment: Thanks again! I tried again the REST api with Neo4j 2.3 and the issue seems to persist. I'm not sure if it's a problem of my code, though. Could you mention in your answer the issue fix, possibly providing a link, so that I can accept your answer?